# Python if statement to get the latest value

Tags: python-3.x, excel, if-statement

How to do the same if statement in Python as in excel.

- create a new column in my DataFrame based on the latest available value from other columns

to obtain this in excel i did this:
=IF(G2="September";G2;IF(F2="August";F2;IF(E2="July";E2;IF(D2="June";D2;IF(C2="May";C2;"NaN")))))

also see screentshot [Sceenshot of excel if statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHlhU.png)

i need to go from this [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjiSB.png)

to this [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6IYW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `max` with `datetime.datetime.strptime` as the key:

```py
months_used = ['January', 'April', 'August']

import datetime
last_month_used = max(months_used, key=lambda month:datetime.datetime.strptime(month,'%B'))
#               = 'August'
```

See also: [strptime behaviour documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Alternatively, you can use python's `max` with `aReferenceListOfAllTheMonths.index` as the key:

```py
allmonths=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'November', 'December']
last_month_used = max(months_used, key=allmonths.index)
#               = 'August'
```

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary:

```
allmonths={'January':0, 'February':1, 'March':2, 'April':3, 'May':4, 'June':5, 'July':6, 'August':7, 'September':8, 'October':9, 'November':10, 'December':11}
last_month_used = max(months_used, key=allmonths.get)
#               = 'August'
```

Comment: Hi Stef,

i cannot see how your solution will solve my problem as i have to check multiple columns in my df. 

which part of your code tell python to check the different columns and return the max value to a new column?

Comment: Dear Frederik, I cannot see in your question under what form or using which libraries your data is presented, so I decided to present my solution with just one row. I called the row `months_used`. This row contains elements from three columns: "January", "April", and "August".

Comment: Hi Stef,
i have updated the question with a before and after screenshot. I obtained the "After" result by writing the formula in excel as shown in the question. However i would very much like to avoid exporting to excel from python and then importing to python again. If i somehow could do the same code in python where i check all the concerned columns to get the last/max month - and go through row by row.

hope it makes sense

but anyway thank you for the taking the time to answer

Comment: Have you tried with `max(months_used, key=lambda month:datetime.datetime.strptime(month,'%B'))`, where `months_used` is the list of all months in the row, from the first column "last month used_x" to the last column "last month used"?

Comment: Yes and i got the error: KeyError: 

"['last month used_06'] not in index"


Here is the whole code: 

df["month"]=max(df[["last month used_05","last month used_06","last month used_x",
                            "last month used_y","last month used"]], 
                    key=lambda month:datetime.datetime.strptime(month,'%B'))

note: that i did just change the name of the 2 first columns as i saw the naming of the first was the same as the third and the second was the same as the fourth.